# Java Exercise: Printing asterisks Triangle and its inverted triangle using recursion method

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion, data-structures

I need to print a triangle and its inverted triangle (standing on its tip). I manage to print out only the triangle. I know I can easily use for loop but I want to know how to make use recursion and in my case, I don't know how to print the both triangle and the inverted one.Thank you.

```
Example desired output:
*
**
***
****
****
***
**
*
```

My code:

```
public class Recursion1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Recursion1 me = new Recursion1();
        me.doIt();
    }

    public void doIt() {        
        nums(4);
    }

    public String nums(int counts) {
        if (counts <= 0) {
            return "";
        }   

        String p = nums(counts - 1);
        p = p +"*";
        System.out.print(p);
        System.out.println();

        return p;
    }
}
```

My result:

```
Results:
*
**
***
****
```

Comment: Do it again, but in reverse. If you think about it for a while you will see how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rethink the problem, this could be a possible solution:

```
public class Recursion1 {
private static int endValue;
private static int startValue = 1 ;

public Recursion1(int endValue){
    Recursion1.endValue = endValue;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Recursion1 me = new Recursion1(4);
    me.doIt();
}

public void doIt() {        
    nums("*");
}

public String nums(String value) {
    if( startValue == endValue){
        System.out.println(value);
    }else{
        System.out.println(value);
        startValue ++;
        value = value.concat("*");
        nums(value);
        value = value.substring(1);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
    return value;
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you elaborate the public String nums method more. I'm not quite catch the reason behind this method. Also, the code above did quite a great job printing out the asterisks however, it seems like it just print out from one asterisk ( * ) up to 4 asterisks ( **** ) and it not repeating print out 4 asterisks ( **** ) back down wards to one asterisk ( * ) instead, after print out ( **** ), it starts print just three ( *** ). I've tried to adjust the numbering and stuff but still could not figure out how I can print exactly like my post above. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to keep the creation of the resulting `String` separate from printing. That would allow you to do anything else you want with the result and it's likely to be more efficient. Also for efficiency, `StringBuilder` is recommended as it avoids creating and discarding many `String` objects. Also for efficiency prefer appending a single `char` instead of a `String` with a single char.

Here is a solution with these in mind. You pass as argument an initial count of zero, the number of lines and a new `StringBuilder`. The number of `*` appended increases up to half the number of lines and then decreases. New line is appended in each recursive call.

```
public void doIt() {
    String p = nums(0, 7, new StringBuilder());
    System.out.print(p);
}

public String nums(int counts, int lines, StringBuilder b) {
    if (counts == lines)
        return b.toString();

    int size = counts < lines / 2 ?
               counts :
               lines - counts - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; ++i)
        b.append('*');
    b.append('\n');

    return nums(counts + 1, lines, b);
}
```